# Column width when cell in first row spans multiple columns

Tags: css, html, html-table

How can I specify the widths of columns in a table having a specified width and using fixed table layout when a cell in the first row spans multiple columns?

Using the following code, the first column gets the desired width of `100px`. The 3 the other columns get equal width, which is not what I want. How can I let column 2 have width `200px`, column 3 `400px`, and column 4 fill whatever space is left while still using `table-layout: fixed`?

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 100px">First cell</td>
      <td colspan="3">Spanning cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="background: red">1</td>
      <td style="width: 200px; background: blue">2</td>
      <td style="width: 400px; background: green">3</td>
      <td style="background: yellow">4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colgroup` and `col`:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <colgroup>
       <col style="width: 100px;">
       <col style="width: 200px;">
       <col style="width: 400px;">
    </colgroup>
   <tr>
      <td>First cell</td>
      <td colspan="3">Spanning cell</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="background: red">1</td>
      <td style="background: blue">2</td>
      <td style="background: green">3</td>
      <td style="background: yellow">4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/07mno6r5/

Comment: Using `colgroup` is irrelevant here, and illogical: what’s the point of grouping some columns, when there are no other columns? What matters is the `col` elements and setting widths on them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Unless I'm mistaken a `col` is only valid within a `colgroup`.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element

Comment: To add to that slightly, you can omit the `colgroup` if you want but it will be inserted by the browser.  The way MDN puts it is that `colgroup`'s start tag can be omitted (odd way of putting it)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Colgroup to set column width as:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
 <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 100px"/>
    <col style="width: 200px;"/>
    <col style="width: 400px"/>
    <col style="width: auto"/>            
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td colspan="3">Spanning cell</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: red">1</td>
    <td style="background: blue">2</td>
    <td style="background: green">3</td>
    <td style="background: yellow">4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7g2fhpp/)